# Is there a special name for a group of interrelated tables within a database?

Tags: sql

I've made a web application framework and I'm documenting the purpose of some of my tables and I'm looking for a good word which means 'group of interrelated tables'. Some of these tables may not actually be related in the database but they are related in the sense that they are all used as part of the core application. The best word I can think of is 'dataset' but that may be a little confusing for many whom have heard this used to mean the result of a query. Is there a more appropriate term for this concept?

Comment: Something like Schema in the SQL Server sense?

Comment: maybe just go with "group of interrelated tables"?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I've always heard that word used to describe the structure of the data but it doesn't really delineate a group of tables.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I guess I could invent a name like: 'This is a core data table for holding user information.'

Comment: I thought there would be a more formal concept of this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, MS SQL Server does provide Schemas as a way to logically group together related database objects, like tables, views and stored procedures, among others. I would suppose that it may be considered a formal enough term, as evidenced in it's use in [this whitepaper on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I guess it can mean exactly that. I had never heard that word used like this before.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think I had heard it in that sense outside SQL Server either, hence my initial remark.

Comment: Schemas are not a SQL Server concept. They are defined in the SQL standard and several other DBMS also support schemas.

Comment: I realise that. I was merely stating that I hadn't come across that usage of the term before starting work. I too knew only the meaning that OP stated.